How to check only the checkbox with IDs from a datatable according to a string of IDs via Ajax request? PHP, JQuery and Datatable
Scenario:
The datatable has a column with checkbox id="sel_customer" referring to the IDs of Customers with several rows.
The Ajax request (data) returns a string with the list of IDs of the Customers that I want to select when loading the datatable.
How can I select the sel_customer checkbox of the datatable according to the list of IDs returned via Ajax?
NOTE: sometimes it enters the $(".sel_customer").each(function (i, el) { but most of the time it seems to ignore the function.
How can I mark only the checkbox with IDs of a datatable according to a string of IDs via Ajax request?
Datatable - When loading the datatable, mark the IDs checkbox according to the Ajax data IDs.
Customers.php
<!-- Datatable1 -->
    <table id="table1" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">SEL</th>
                <th width="5%">ID</th>
                <th width="50%">NAME</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <!-- NUMBER OF COLUMNS ABOVE -->
                <th colspan="3" style="text-align:left">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="selecionar_tudo">Check all</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="insere_selecionados" disabled>Add customer checked</button>
                </th>
                <th style="text-align:left"></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

Customer.js
        customer.datatable = $('#table1').DataTable({
            ...datatable,
            ajax: 'Customer.php',
            cache: false,
            columns: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    data: null,
                    render: function(data) {
                        return `<input type='checkbox' id='sel_customer' class='sel_customer' style='display: block; margin: 0 auto'>`;
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'id',
                },
                {
                    data: 'name',
                },
            ]
        });


            //Customers
            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: '../Rota.php?send=customers
                data: '',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {
                    // return 5,6,7,8 (returns list of IDs)
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    //data = '5,6,7,8';

                    if(data.length > 0) {

                        alert(data); //5,6,7,8

                        $(".sel_customer").each(function (i, el) { //It seems to ignore and not enter the function
                            //I think this line brings the Datatable IDs, here is the code snippet to correct
                            let vtr = $(this).closest("tr");
                            let vid = [vtr.find('td').eq(1).html()]; //get the datatable ID
            
                            if(vtr.find('td').eq(1).html() == 5) {//If id = 5, mark the row in the datatable
                                
                                $(this).prop("checked", true);// this doesn't work
                                
                            }
                        }).promise().done(function () { 
                            //It works but it only brings the last record of .each, I need them all
                        });
                    }
                    //return;
                },
                error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('An error ocurred');
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });


    /*** FROM HERE ON THE CODE IS OK ***/
        /*** Check all Datatable checkboxes ***/

        var marcar_tudo = true;
        var json = [];
        var lista_inserir = [];
        var itens = '';

        $("#selecionar_tudo").click(function () {

            let checked = true;

            if(!marcar_tudo) {
                checked = false;
            } else {
                checked = true;
            }

            $(".sel_customer").each(function (i, el) {
                $(el).prop("checked", checked);
            })

            btnInserirTodos()

            if(!marcar_tudo) {
                marcar_tudo = true;
                $(this).html("Check All")
            } else{
                marcar_tudo = false;
                $(this).html("Uncheck All")
            }
        })
            
        customer.datatable.on('change', '.sel_customer', function () {
            btnInserirTodos()
        })

        function btnInserirTodos() {

            //zerar array
            lista_inserir = [];
            let total = 0;

            $(".sel_customer").each(function (i, el) {

                if($(el).is(":checked")) {
                    let tr = $(el).closest("tr");
                    let id = [tr.find('td').eq(1).html()];
                    lista_inserir.push(id);
                    total++;
                }
            })
            
            //Transformar array em string
            itens = lista_inserir.toString();

            if(total > 0) {
                if(total == 1) {
                    $("#insere_selecionados").prop("disabled", false).html(`Add ${total} customer`);
                } else {
                    $("#insere_selecionados").prop("disabled", false).html(`Add ${total} customers`);
                }
            } else {
                $("#insere_selecionados").prop("disabled", true).html("Add customer");
            }
        }

        $("#insere_selecionados").click(function () {
            
            let json = {
                ids: itens
            };

            Swal.fire({
                icon: "success",
                title: "Your work has been saved",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            });

            $("#insere_selecionados").prop("disabled", true).html("Inserting...");

            return;

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'Rota.php?action=insert',
                data: json,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {
                    //data = JSON.parse(data);
                    //alert(data);
                    if(data == 'Inserted successfully') {
                        $("#table1").DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                    $("#insere_selecionados").prop("disabled", true).html("Add customer")
                },
                error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('An error ocurred');
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            })//Ajax
        })

.

Since you are using AJAX as your data source, that first part, customer.datatable = $('#table1').DataTable(...) will be asynchronous. So the "following" AJAX request might return, before your datatable has even been filled initially - in which case $(".sel_customer") is likely not finding any such elements to begin with.

"The Ajax request (data) returns a string with the list of IDs of the Customers that I want to select when loading the datatable." - if you only want to do this when the table gets initially populated(?), then why are you fetching this data via a separate request to begin with? Why does the Customer.php not directly deliver the info, which of these customers are supposed to be selected, as part of the data structure it returns? And then inside your render function, you would directly create either a checked or an unchecked checkbox, for the current record.

id='sel_customer' - since this executes for the first cell in all rows, this will create duplicate IDs.

I solve the issue using initComplete of the datatable
new DataTable('#myTable', {
initComplete: function (settings, json) {
alert('DataTables has finished its initialisation.');
}
});
When the table finishes loading I select the IDs from the string.
